# "The editor has encountered an unexpected error" After add defer tag to java script

Tags: filters, javascript, jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I added below script to add defer tag in javascripts. Once it added to function.php
Gets error on create post "The editor has encountered an unexpected error." I cannot create or edit post.
How can i add defer tag to javascripts without affecting to the editor. I don't have mush experience in coding. Thanks.

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', function ( $tag, $handle ) {

    if ( 'jquery-core' !== $handle )
        return $tag;

    return str_replace( ' src', ' defer="defer" src', $tag );
}, 10, 2 );
```

**console errors are**

> TypeError: d.media is not a function
> wp-includes/js/dist/media-utils.min.js?ver=9ad24b42cc69f241229ded4dc61409fb:2:6432)
> wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:63:107) and
> more..

Comment: Why are you trying to defer scripts?

Comment: When i check site speed on Gtmetrix, it says  "JavaScript is parsed during initial page load. Defer parsing JavaScript to reduce blocking of page rendering." 
So, i tried with above code and it works well. But got error on above.
Any other ways to Defer parsing JavaScript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as your aim is to improve loading on the front end, the best approach would be to simply not add the `defer` attribute when loading in the admin area, like so.

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', function ( $tag, $handle ) {
    if ( 'jquery-core' !== $handle ) {
        return $tag;
    }
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $tag = str_replace( ' src', ' defer="defer" src', $tag );
    }
    return $tag;
}, 10, 2 );
```

As the editor has a number of scripts, often depending on other scripts already loading, it's generally not a good idea to try and use `async` or `defer` in the admin.

Comment: Great. It works well as i expected. Thank you..